# Filtering a bootstrap-vue datatable in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a very simple table with bootstrap-vue where i can filter my data using the built-in filter.
The problem i have now is that i want to add another filter where i can input a number and get all the rows where `value` is higher than the specified number. I don't really know where to start with this, since i'm already using a filter. Can anyone suggest an approach i can take for thi? Any advice is appreciated.

```
<template>
  <div class="overflow-auto">
    <b-form-fieldset horizontal label="Filter" class="col-6">
      <b-input v-model="filter" placeholder="Filter table.."></b-input>
    </b-form-fieldset>

    <b-table
      id="my-table"
      :filter="filter" 
      :fields="fields"
      :items="items"
      small
    ></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      filter: '',
      fields: [{'key': 'asset', 'sortable': true}, {'key': 'value', 'sortable': false}, {'key': 'address', 'sortable': false}],
      items: []
    }
  },

  computed: {
    rows() {
      return this.items.length
    }
  },

}
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#custom-filter-function

Comment: Not really, because in my case i would need to have multiple filters, but i found nothing about that case on the docs

Comment: If you want to keep the existing filter and add yours, you could create a `computed` property, for example `prefilteredItems() { return this.items.filter(({value}) => value > 3); }` and use it in your template `:items="prefilteredItems"` (replacing `3` with the value of a field you might have but which is not in your code snippet)

Comment: That would make sense, as long as the original array is not mutated.

Comment: @blex i tried this and it worked. Is there any way you can post this as an aswer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the existing filter and add yours, you could create a `computed` property, for example `prefilteredItems` and use it in your template:

```html
<template>
  <!-- ... -->
  <b-input v-model="minValue" placeholder="Minimum value..."></b-input>
  <!-- ... -->
  <b-table
    :items="prefilteredItems"
  ></b-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      filter: '',
      minValue: 0,
      /* ... */
      items: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    prefilteredItems() {
      return this.items.filter(({ value }) => value >= this.minValue);
    },
    rows() {
      return this.prefilteredItems.length
    }
  },
}
</script>
```